# How can I Drag and Drop Images/Text on Canvas and save canvas as HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, html, html5-canvas

How can I show Html/pdf on page(Using Canvas) and add images and text by dragging and dropping them and save Canvas as html ?
I have tried jQuery UI for drag and drop images and text but it's not up to mark. 
Can I load html into canvas and perform the drag and drop on canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't load actual html into canvas itself (largely for security reasons).**

This canvas library does a fairly good job of "faking it":

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

But with a little learning, you may find that canvas itself has all the formatting/drawing capabilities you need.

- Drawing basic elements: lines, rectangles, arcs, images
- Drawing text including fonts and font sizes
- Drawing custom paths
- Drawing effects: opacity, shadowing, compositing (blending), clipping
- Strokes, fills (including gradients), patterns
- Transforms: move, rotate, scale, skew

And you can tie into window events (mouse, touch, requestAnimationFrame, etc) to get more:

- Drag/Drop
- Animations
- Transitions
- Spriting
- Capture & Alter video streams